# SQL display DISTINCT rows for lowest value

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am using MySQL 5.5. I have a SQL question please.

I have the following tables (oneToMany - one Employee to many Locations):

```
+----------+   +-------------------+  +-----------+
| EMPLOYEE |   | EMPLOYEE_LOCATION |  | LOCATION  |
 ----------     -------------------    -----------
|ID        |   |EMP_ID             |  | ID        |
|          |   |LOC_ID             |  | LATITUDE  |
|          |   |                   |  | LONGITUDE |
+----------+   +-------------------+  +-----------+
```

Data:

```
+----+          +-------------+       +-------------------------------+
| ID |          |EMP_ID|LOC_ID|       |ID | LATITUDE    | LONGITUDE   |  
+----+          +-------------+       +-------------------------------+
| 1  |          |  1   |  1   |       | 1 | 28.80000000 |-25.76666700 |
| 2  |          |  1   |  2   |       | 2 | 27.35000000 |-25.76266700 |
| 3  |          |  1   |  3   |       | 3 | 27.95000000 |-25.66666700 |
+----+          |  2   |  4   |       | 4 | 26.85000000 |-25.76666700 |
                |  2   |  5   |       | 5 | 28.85000000 |-25.76666700 |
                |  4   |  6   |       | 6 | 28.85000000 |-25.86666701 |
                +-------------+       +-------------------------------+
```

My SQL:

```
select e.ID,
( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( o.LATITUDE) ) * cos( radians( o.LONGITUDE) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians( o.LATITUDE) ) ) ) AS distance
from
    www.employee as e
inner join
    www.employee_location as eo
        on e.id=eo.EMP_ID 
inner join
    www.location as o
        on eo.LOC_ID=o.ID        
order by distance
```

Is returning:

```
ID| DISTANCE
--+------------------
3 | 8622.766267835324
2 | 8630.684502219874
1 | 8633.923476508438
1 | 8697.058324230797
1 | 8728.471585032592
2 | 8760.772628068693
```

I am trying to formulate my SQL so that it only returns a row for each EMPLOYEE (3 rows). Each row returned is the one with the **lowest** DISTANCE value ordered by DISTANCE.

For example, I would want the following:

```
ID| DISTANCE
--+------------------
3 | 8622.766267835324
2 | 8630.684502219874
1 | 8633.923476508438
```

Any help appreciated, thank you.

Comment: mySQL doesn't support window functions which could be used to derive this.  Before their use and in mySQL the option is to wrap your query in an outer query allowing you to use aggregation and a group by.

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to have a subquery. Just do a group by in your query and a min on the distance -

```
select e.ID,
min(( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( o.LATITUDE) ) * cos( radians( o.LONGITUDE) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians( o.LATITUDE) ) ) )) AS distance
from
    www.employee as e
inner join
    www.employee_location as eo
        on e.id=eo.EMP_ID 
inner join
    www.location as o
        on eo.LOC_ID=o.ID   
group by e.ID     
order by distance
```

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use a outer query and get the minimum like

```
select ID, min(distance) as mindistance from (
select e.ID,
( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( o.LATITUDE) ) * cos( radians( o.LONGITUDE) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians( o.LATITUDE) ) ) ) AS distance
from
    www.employee as e
inner join
    www.employee_location as eo
        on e.id=eo.EMP_ID 
inner join
    www.location as o
        on eo.LOC_ID=o.ID ) xxx
group by ID;
```